# Subdomain Redirects to main domain on Google Chrome

Tags: dns, subdomain, appdomain

I created a subdomain using Cloudflare, GoDaddy and Heroku.

The domain is api.domain.com.

I can access it correctly on Microsoft Edge and Firefox, but whenever I try to access it on google Chrome it redirects me to domain.com/api for some reason.

Comment: I believe this is an issue with your Chrome. Have you tested from different networks?

Comment: Yeah, it probably was. I just had to restart my computer and it started working.

Comment: It works also in incognito mode. I got same problem.